# How to control Pex digging deep

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moles, pex

When I try to do an Pex exploration on my source that calls to certain system files and functions. Many times I get path bounds exceeded in the system file class functions. How can I get Pex to run the exploration on only my code and maybe one level deeper.

Comment: Sad to see that I am not getting any answers for my query